# Trying to filter the top 10 entries using R?

Tags: r

So I have a dataset of countries GNI Per Capita and suicide numbers and I am trying to filter the top 10 countries with the highest GNI only. My problem is that in my dataset I have duplicate entries for countries for GNI as I also have suicide statistics for a particular age group per gender for every country.

I tried applying the following code using the top_n function in Dplyr :

```
top_highest_gni <- df_filter_ages %>%   group_by(as.numeric(as.character(GNI.per.capita..PPP..current.international.....NY.GNP.PCAP.PP.CD.))) %>% 
      top_n(10)
```

However this does not effect my dataset at all and no error message comes up and I am not sure why? Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Data looks like this :

```
Country   Year   Sex  GNI
Albania   2012   F    290000
Albania   2012   M    290000
UK        2012   F    2222222222
UK        2012   M    2222222222
```

**Edit**

As suggested I added the summarise function and ran this code :

```
df_filter_ages %>%
  group_by(country) %>% 
  summarise(max = max(as.numeric(as.character(GNI.per.capita..PPP..current.international.....NY.GNP.PCAP.PP.CD.)))) %>% 
  top_n(2)
```

**And output is :**

```
Selecting by max
     max
1 119330
```

**Desired output:**

```
Country   Year   Sex  GNI

UK        2012   F    2222222222
UK        2012   M    2222222222
Albania   2012   F    290000
Albania   2012   M    290000
```

Comment: Here your input and expected output are almost same, which do not help us much to see what you want.  Can you paste the output of `dput(head(data, 50))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try including the `summarise()` function after the `group_by()` function and before the `top_n()` function.

Example:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3), 
                 y = c(4, 5, 6), 
                 z = c(1, 20, 50))

df %>%
  group_by(x) %>% 
  summarise(max = max(z)) %>% 
  top_n(2)

#  A tibble: 2 x 2
#       x total
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     2    20
# 2     3    50
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I applied the above and it only returns the highest value within the GNI Column? (Edited my question to include what was run and exact output

Comment: Did you `group_by(Country, Year, Sex)`? That's really odd that it only returns 1 value: the highest value in the GNI column. `group_by()` then `summarise()` never behave like that. If you grouped by country, i.e., `group_by(country)`, a country value has to print out next to `119330`.